# Django user restriction in input fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Template:

```
<td class="post_hidden" style="min-width:70px;">
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="planner" 
 id="post_planner_{{ shelf.shelf_no }}" value="{% if shelf.post_planner_percentage %}{{ shelf.post_planner_percentage }}{% endif %}" tabindex="11">%
   </td>
```

Model:

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.db.models import Min

from testing.models import (
    BugsPostTesting,
    BugsPreTesting,
    BugsScript,
    ResultOptions,
    ResultsStbs,
    ResultsTests,
)
from testing.views import calculate_health_score


def save_shelf(request):
    """Saves the general result information for each shelf"""
    if request.is_ajax:
        results_stb_id = int(request.POST.get('test_id'))
        shelf_no = int(request.POST.get('shelf_no'))
        connection = int(request.POST.get('connection'))
        if request.POST.get('test_case') != '':
            test_case = int(request.POST.get('test_case'))
        else:
            test_case = None
        pre_planner = request.POST.get('pre_planner')
        pre_details = request.POST.get('pre_details')
        pre_affirm = request.POST.get('pre_affirm')
        pre_parser = request.POST.get('pre_parser')
        pre_log = request.POST.get('pre_log')
        pre_campaigns = request.POST.get('pre_campaigns')
        pre_assets = request.POST.get('pre_assets')
        pre_total_assets = request.POST.get('pre_total_assets')
        time_of_failure = request.POST.get('time_of_failure')
        script_details = request.POST.get('script_details')
        post_planner = request.POST.get('post_planner')
        post_details = request.POST.get('post_details')
        uptime_days = request.POST.get('uptime_days')
        uptime_hours = request.POST.get('uptime_hours')
        uptime_mins = request.POST.get('uptime_mins')
        post_affirm = request.POST.get('post_affirm')
        post_parser = request.POST.get('post_parser')
        post_log = request.POST.get('post_log')
        post_log_one = request.POST.get('post_log_one')
        post_campaigns = request.POST.get('post_campaigns')
        post_assets = request.POST.get('post_assets')
        post_total_assets = request.POST.get('post_total_assets')

        pre_result = int(request.POST.get('pre_result'))
        script_result = int(request.POST.get('script_result'))
        post_result = int(request.POST.get('post_result'))

        shelf_record = ResultsStbs.objects.select_related(
            'pre_testing_result',
            'script_result',
            'post_result',
        ).get(
            results_test_id=results_stb_id,
            shelf_no=shelf_no,
        )

        if pre_planner:
            shelf_record.pre_planner_percentage = int(pre_planner)
        else:
            shelf_record.pre_planner_percentage = None

        if time_of_failure:
            shelf_record.script_time_of_failure = time_of_failure
        else:
            shelf_record.script_time_of_failure = None

        if post_planner:
            shelf_record.post_planner_percentage = int(post_planner)

        else:
            shelf_record.post_planner_percentage = None

        if uptime_days:
            shelf_record.system_days = uptime_days
        else:
            shelf_record.system_days = None

        if uptime_hours:
            shelf_record.system_hours = uptime_hours
        else:
            shelf_record.system_hours = None

        if uptime_mins:
            shelf_record.system_mins = uptime_mins
        else:
            shelf_record.system_mins = None

        # AdSmart
        if pre_campaigns:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_campaigns = int(pre_campaigns)
        else:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_campaigns = None

        if pre_assets:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_assets = int(pre_assets)
        else:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_assets = None

        if pre_total_assets:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_total_assets = int(pre_total_assets)
        else:
            shelf_record.pre_ads_total_assets = None

        if post_campaigns:
            shelf_record.ads_campaigns = int(post_campaigns)
        else:
            shelf_record.ads_campaigns = None

        if post_assets:
            shelf_record.ads_assets = int(post_assets)
        else:
            shelf_record.ads_assets = None

        if post_total_assets:
            shelf_record.ads_total_assets = int(post_total_assets)
        else:
            shelf_record.ads_total_assets = None

        results_stb_id = shelf_record.results_stb_id

        shelf_record.network_connection_id = connection
        shelf_record.tr_test_case_id = test_case
        shelf_record.pre_testing = pre_details
        shelf_record.pre_affirm = pre_affirm
        shelf_record.pre_parser_output = pre_parser
        shelf_record.pre_log_url = pre_log
        shelf_record.script = script_details
        shelf_record.post_testing = post_details
        shelf_record.affirm = post_affirm
        shelf_record.parser_output = post_parser
        shelf_record.log_url = post_log
        shelf_record.log_url_one = post_log_one

        pre_option = ResultOptions.objects.get(result_option_id=pre_result)
        script_option = ResultOptions.objects.get(
            result_option_id=script_result
        )
        post_option = ResultOptions.objects.get(result_option_id=post_result)

        shelf_record.pre_testing_result = pre_option
        shelf_record.script_result = script_option
        shelf_record.post_result = post_option

        try:
            shelf_record.save()

            try:
                results_test_id = shelf_record.results_test_id
                calculate_health_score(results_test_id, results_stb_id)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                message = e.__cause__
            message = 'Saved.'
        except IntegrityError as e:
            message = e.__cause__

    else:
        message = 'No request recieved.'

    return HttpResponse(message)
shareeditdeleteflag
```

Js

```
   function saveShelf(shelfNo){
// Saves the information for each shelf.
var releaseName = '{{ test_details.test_release_name }}';

// Set element IDs
var connectionId='network_connection_'+shelfNo;
var testCaseId='test_case_'+shelfNo;
var prePlannerId='pre_planner_'+shelfNo;
var preDetailsId='pre_details_'+shelfNo;
var preAffirmId='pre_affirm_'+shelfNo;
var preParserId='pre_parser_output_'+shelfNo;
var preLogId='pre_log_url_'+shelfNo;
var scriptDetailsId='script_details_'+shelfNo;
var timeOfFailureId='time_of_failure_'+shelfNo;
var postPlannerId='post_planner_'+shelfNo;
var postDetailsId='post_details_'+shelfNo;
var uptimeDaysId='uptime_days_'+shelfNo;
var uptimeHoursId='uptime_hours_'+shelfNo;
var uptimeMinsId='uptime_mins_'+shelfNo;
var postAffirmId='post_affirm_'+shelfNo;
var postParserId='post_parser_output_'+shelfNo;
var postLogId='post_log_url_'+shelfNo;
var postLogOneId='post_log_url_one_'+shelfNo;

var preResultName='pre_result_'+shelfNo;
var scriptResultName='script_result_'+shelfNo;
var postResultName='post_result_'+shelfNo;

// Shelf results
var preResult=radioCheck(preResultName);
var scriptResult=radioCheck(scriptResultName);
var postResult=radioCheck(postResultName);

// Retrieve values to be saved
var connection=document.getElementById(connectionId).value;
var testCase=document.getElementById(testCaseId).value;
var preDetails=document.getElementById(preDetailsId).value;
var scriptDetails=document.getElementById(scriptDetailsId).value;
var timeOfFailure=document.getElementById(timeOfFailureId).value;
var postDetails=document.getElementById(postDetailsId).value;
var uptimeDays=document.getElementById(uptimeDaysId).value;
var uptimeHours=document.getElementById(uptimeHoursId).value;
var uptimeMins=document.getElementById(uptimeMinsId).value;

if (releaseName != 'Now TV') {
    var prePlanner=document.getElementById(prePlannerId).value;
    var preAffirm=document.getElementById(preAffirmId).value;
    var preParser=document.getElementById(preParserId).value;
    var preLog=document.getElementById(preLogId).value;
    var postPlanner=document.getElementById(postPlannerId).value;
    var postAffirm=document.getElementById(postAffirmId).value;
    var postParser=document.getElementById(postParserId).value;
    var postLog=document.getElementById(postLogId).value;
    var postLogOne=document.getElementById(postLogOneId).value;
}
else {
    var prePlanner='';
    var preAffirm='';
    var preParser='';
    var preLog='';
    var postPlanner='';
    var postAffirm='';
    var postParser='';
    var postLog='';
    var postLogOne='';
}

// AdSmart values
var adsmart={{ test_details.adsmart }}

var preCampaigns="";
var preAssets="";
var preTotalAssets="";
var postCampaigns="";
var postAssets="";
var postTotalAssets="";

if (adsmart==1) {
    var preCampaignsId='pre_campaigns_'+shelfNo;
    var preCampaigns=document.getElementById(preCampaignsId).value;
    var preAssetsId='pre_assets_'+shelfNo;
    var preAssets=document.getElementById(preAssetsId).value;
    var preTotalAssetsId='pre_total_assets_'+shelfNo;
    var preTotalAssets=document.getElementById(preTotalAssetsId).value;

    var postCampaignsId='post_campaigns_'+shelfNo;
    var postCampaigns=document.getElementById(postCampaignsId).value;
    var postAssetsId='post_assets_'+shelfNo;
    var postAssets=document.getElementById(postAssetsId).value;
    var postTotalAssetsId='post_total_assets_'+shelfNo;
    var postTotalAssets=document.getElementById(postTotalAssetsId).value;
}

var postUrl = "{% url 'testing:save_shelf' %}";
var testId = "{{ test_details.pk }}";

var notificationId = 'notification_shelf_' + shelfNo;
var notification = document.getElementById(notificationId);
notification.innerHTML = 'Saving...';

$.ajax( {
    url: postUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: {'test_id':testId,
        'shelf_no':shelfNo,
        'connection':connection,
        'test_case':testCase,
        'pre_result':preResult,
        'pre_planner':prePlanner,
        'pre_details':preDetails,
        'pre_affirm':preAffirm,
        'pre_parser':preParser,
        'pre_log':preLog,
        'pre_campaigns':preCampaigns,
        'pre_assets':preAssets,
        'pre_total_assets':preTotalAssets,
        'script_result':scriptResult,
        'script_details':scriptDetails,
        'time_of_failure':timeOfFailure,
        'post_result':postResult,
        'post_planner':postPlanner,
        'post_details':postDetails,
        'uptime_days':uptimeDays,
        'uptime_hours':uptimeHours,
        'uptime_mins':uptimeMins,
        'post_affirm':postAffirm,
        'post_parser':postParser,
        'post_log':postLog,
        'post_log_one':postLogOne,
        'post_campaigns':postCampaigns,
        'post_assets':postAssets,
        'post_total_assets':postTotalAssets,
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);},
    success:function ( returnedData, textStatus, jqXHR ){
        notification.innerHTML = returnedData;
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        window.setTimeout(function() { notification.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'; }, 3000);
        zeroSymptomCheck(testId, shelfNo);
        defectInformation();
    },
})
}
```

I run a script to get devices usage percentage. I am writing this data to mysql db. We've got a django portal which reads data from there.

the input saves all datas from (1-100). When the percentage is 0, it does not save. When I refresh the page, it leaves blank. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What did you expect to get when page get refreshed?

Comment: Hi @nik_m Thanks for your comment.The input does not accept 0 value. So, I am trying to find out the reason.Any ideas ?

Comment: value="{% if shelf.post_planner_percentage %}{{ shelf.post_planner_percentage }}{% endif %}"

Comment: By saying "0" value, do you mean the empty string, `""` ?

Comment: Not really. When you enter 0 to input field and then press the save button. it does not save the value. Apart from 0, it saves all the data. For instance, device usage percentage can be from 0 to 100%.

Comment: By saying "does not save the value" you mean in the database. Would you mind share your `views.py` (where the actual save happens)?